# Is it safe to assume that potential pathogens are only present on the surface of animal meats?

Tags: food-safety, meat, raw, raw-meat, kitchen-safety

In [this Seasoned Advice answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/112379/37445) regarding meats, the writer states:

> Additionally, we generally assume that any potential pathogens are only present on the surface of whole muscle cuts.

Is this a valid assumption for all animal meats (animal meats to include fish, game, beef, poultry, pork, insects, et al.)?

Answer (score 2):

No, this is a feature primarily of beef, some wild game, and poultry. Meats like pork and many kinds of fish may contain parasites and thus need to be cooked to higher temperatures than eg beef or duck (pork) or frozen before cooking (many kinds of fish) to minimise the risk of illness.

Comment: Thank you Johanna.  Is it a safe assumption just for beef?  Also, which game meats, and which not?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket It's also a safe assumption for duck. Among wild animals, I know that moose, reindeer, deer, and most (maybe all?) wild birds are safe to eat cooked rare. I do no have a complete list, I'm afraid.

Comment: I suspect that poultry varies by country -- in the US, chickens are *not* inoculated against salmonella, so it's a risk.  The CDC estimates [26k hospitalizations and 420 deaths per year](https://www.cdc.gov/salmonella/index.html), but they don't have that broken down by undercooked poultry, live animals, or undercooked eggs.  (and they also mention it can be in more than just poultry)

Answer (score 0):

If we're talking about examined meats that come from certified source then I would say yes.
With a caveat - everything that have interaction with air should be treated as "surface". So if you buy gutted fish the "inside" should be treated as surface. Same with turkey (or chicken) for stuffing.

Comment: Chicken can have salmonella in it, I would not assume the inside of chicken is safe.

Comment: Indeed. No-one ever asked if you want your chicken burger rare, medium or well.

Comment: @GdD hence "examined meats from certified source". You can find salmonella in air proof eggs, game meats can have parasites inside muscles. Controled and checked for pathogens are the key. Otherwise we would be talking "there is also salmonella on vegies".

Comment: I can't agree with you on this. Even if I bought a chicken from a very reputable source I would always cook it to a safe temperature as there's still a relatively high risk.

Comment: The risk is actually higher in the US than EU, because of legislation on poultry vaccination.

Comment: @Tetsujin...@GdD... see: https://www.chefsteps.com/activities/chicken-tartare

Comment: @moscafj - I'd rather stick pins in my eyes ;))